# Is there a man who lies under Masjid-Al-Aqsa?

Tags: day-of-judgement

I've heard once a story about a man who lies under the Masjid-Al-Aqsa. He will wake up when the Day of Judgement is near and his properties are: that he has a third eye between his two eyes. I was told he will ask every single human being what is the true religion and then kill him.

Is this a myth or a true story?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Masih al-Dajjal](https://islamqa.info/en/8806) and the beast of the earth ([27:82](https://quran.com/27/82)) are relevant concepts. I think you might be referring to Dajjal, though he does not have three eyes, rather he is called one-eyed because his other eye will be defective. Dajjal is also not under Masjid-al-aqsa and will also not kill every human.

Comment: Oké, can I regard my story as a myth?

Comment: @AnonymousI It is more of a distortion of one of the signs of the Hour. Please research into the story of Dajjal (AntiChrist) and you can analyze from yourself which parts of your story are true and which are fabrications.

Comment: Oké, I will inshallah but first I have to pray Maghrib and Isa from yesterday since I was too lazy and fell asleep, astaghfirulah and then Fajr and Subh. Do you know what's the correct order to make up for the salats?  First Fajr and subh and then the missed prayers or first the missed prayers and then Fajr and Subh?

Comment: @AnonymousI That would be depend on the circumstances. But you may have look at this relevant link: https://islamqa.info/en/49019

Comment: @Ahmed : I've prayes Subh and Fajr first because it is obligatory to pray the salats of the day first and then the missed prayers according to my stepmum. I'll need to look at some sources to back it up.